# Game (like tic-tac-toe, but with a hole in the middle) where players have to score by getting temples on tiles?

Tags: identify-this-game

The game has eight square pieces placed in a 3x3 array with the middle empty. Think tic-tac-toe but with a hole in the middle.

Each of the eight tiles has a matrix of squares on it, around 8x8 or maybe 10x10.

Each square is water, woods, mountains, vulcanos, large/small temples and, possibly something else too.

During the game play, each of the 8 tiles can be rotated or moved.

The aim of the game is to score by getting many temples, getting temples on many tiles etc.

Each player places his minions along a line they choose, creating a series of dudes, like a nomad clam traveling.

What is the name of the game? Where can I look to find out, should nobody here recognize it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Dokmus](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/199793/dokmus)

This is the part where I describe the game to show that it lines up with your memories, but honestly you've described it in pretty good detail, and there isn't really anything for me to add.  The tiles are 7x7, though.

The tile movement powers are drafted each round by the players, so each player gets 1 special power and three worker placements.

Comment: That **is** the game. However, I'm 101% certain it wasn't called *Dokmus* or I **would** remember as it means a funny thing in my language (or at least it makes for a funny joke in my head, let's not blame the language for my weird brains). I was on that site before but didn't find it: +1 to you for better goole-foo.

Comment: Not Google-fu - I actually learned the game about 2 weeks back.

Comment: Hahahahaha. That's rich. So no google-foo, just a strike of dumb luck? I'll take it! Hope you liked the game.

Comment: I enjoyed it quite a bit!